# Present in a circle

Tags: probability

I found the following riddle:

There are 10 persons in a circle. Person $1$ has a present. This person gives it to the right or to the left with equal probability. The next person with the present does the same. They repeat this until only one person didn't have the present. This person gets to keep the present. Where do you place yourself to have the highest chance to get the present?

I guess you should place yourself on the opposite side of the circle to face person $1$. But how to I proof this mathematically? I can't calculate the probability for each position, because there are infinite possibilities to pass the present to a third person, because two persons could just pass the present to each other every turn. Can someone give me a hint or is there an easier solution?

Comment: You can calculate the probabilities recursively, though I don't see a very fast way to do it.  For example, assume you start at slot $1$ and let $P(i,n)$ be the probability that $i$ is last, given $n$ slots.  Then, recursively $P(2,n)=\frac 12\times 0+\frac 12\times P(2,n-1)$ which implies, barring error, that $P(2,10)=2^{-8}$.  Of course this is also $P(10,10)$.  Continue in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you place yourself, because each position has an equal probability of $1/9$ of getting the present.  We show a connection between this problem and the classical Gambler's Ruin Problem.

The Gambler's Ruin Problem goes like this:  there are two players, $A$ and $B$, who flip a fair coin.  Each time the coin comes up heads, $B$ gives $A$ a coin, and each time the coin comes up tails, $A$ gives $B$ a coin.  Player $A$ initially has $a$ coins and $B$ has $b$ coins, and the game continues until one of the players runs out of coins.  It can be shown that the probability that $A$ wins the game is
$$\frac{a}{a+b}$$
This result is well-known, but we sketch a proof below for completeness.  There is also a version of the problem in which the coin is biased, but we will not need that version.

An alternative formulation of the Gambler's Ruin Problem is to consider $A$'s cumulative gain, which may be negative.  His initial gain is zero.  At each coin flip his gain increases by one or decreases by one with equal probability.  He wins if his gain reaches $b$ without ever reaching $-a$.

Now for the problem of $10$ people standing in a circle, with the present initially at person $1$.  Consider a move of the present from $1$ to $2$ as a move to the right, and a move from $1$ to $10$ as a move to the left.  Then person $2$ gets the present if and only if the present reaches $8$ steps to the left without ever reaching $1$ step to the right from its original position.  This is equivalent to the Gambler's Ruin Problem with $a=1$ and $b=8$, so the probability that person $2$ gets the present is $1 /(1+8) = 1/9$.

Suppose the present reaches $7$ steps to the left without ever reaching $1$ step to the right.  This happens if and only if either person $2$ or $3$ gets the present, and is equivalent to the Gambler's Ruin Problem with $a=2$ and $b=7$, so the associated probability is $2/(2+7) = 2/ 9$.  Since we already know the probability that person $2$ gets the present is $1/9$, the probability that person $3$ gets the present is $2/9 - 1/9 = 1/9$.

At this point I think the pattern is clear, and we will leave it to the reader to complete the proof that the probability that any one person gets the present is $1/9$.

---

Here is a short derivation of the Gambler's Ruin Problem formula. Let $P(a,b)$ be the probability that player $A$ will win the game when he initially has $a$ coins and player $B$ has $b$ coins. The first flip of the coin is heads with probability $1/2$, and tails with probability $1/2$.  If heads, then $A$ now has $a+1$ coins and $B$ has $b-1$ coins; if tails, then $A$ now has $a-1$ coins and $B$ has $b+1$ coins. So
$$P(a,b) = \frac{1}{2} P(a+1, b-1) + \frac{1}{2} P(a-1,b+1)$$
for $a \ge 1$ and $b \ge 1$, with
$P(a,0) = 1$ and $P(0,b) = 0$
for $a>0$ and $b>0$.  It is easy to verify that 
$$P(a,b) = \frac{a}{a+b}$$
satisfies this recursion and the boundary conditions.

---

Edited June 16, 2018: I had the numbers of persons $2$ and $3$ mixed up in the derivation of person $3$'s chance of winning.  (I had written $1$ and $2$ instead of $2$ and $3$.) This has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Placing yourself on the opposite side of the circle is probably the worst position: think about it. After 4 gives there is a 1/16 chance it is 4 steps to the right or left. But it would be in one or the other. The gift has to eventually travel around the circle. The best position would likely be next to the person that starts with the gift. Sure, it could take one step right & then weave a lefterly path: but I think that's the way to bet.

To win from the opposite seat, it must go around one way, then, eventually around the other way: quite unlikely!

Comment: But is it really more likely that the present travels around the circle in only one direction rather than "swinging" from left to right? My idea was that person 1 holds the present most often, the persons adjacent to 1 hold it second most often and so on. I thought about the present like a pendulum.

Comment: You misunderstand: I'm not saying it's not swinging back & forth, just that the result is reaching a certain position. Let's call objective 1 going around & reaching the next person to you sitting opposite the original holder.

Comment: Well I screwed up by accidentally hitting edit. Here's the point. After reaching objective 1 you are in the exact situation I started you with by sitting you next to the original holder. Thus whatever the probability of reaching objective 1, it is exactly that many times more difficult to win sitting opposite than in sitting next to the original holder!

Comment: I just had an idea thanks to your example. Is it possible, that every position has an equal chance to get the present? If you sit right next to person 1, then the present has to travel around the circle in the opposite direction until it reaches the other person next to me. For every postion in the circle at one time one adjacent person holds the present and the other adjacent didn't hold it(objective 1). Now it also has to travel around the circle in the opposite direction. Is this correct?